# Cannot create FisherFaceRecognizer with OpenCV 4 (C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0, face-recognition, opencv-contrib

I'm following an older tutorial on face recognition based on OpenCV in C++ and have an error I can't resolve. The relevant code snippet:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/face.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
...
Ptr<face::FaceRecognizer> model = face::createFisherFaceRecognizer();
model->train(images, labels);
...
```

I have my OpenCV compiled correctly with contrib modules, have them included but it still gives the error:

```
error: 'createFisherFaceRecognizer()' is not a member of 'cv::face'
```

I also trief this one:

```
Ptr<face::FaceRecognizer> model = face::FisherFaceRecognizer_create();
error: 'FisherFaceRecognizer_create()' is not a member of 'cv::face'
```

I looked up the face.hpp, ad the class has a function 'create', so I tried to use it, but this also failed:

```
Ptr<face::FaceRecognizer> model = face::FisherFaceRecognizer.create();
error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
```

which is weird since the function has parameters with default values. All the online solutions I treid failed. What was changed in the newer OpenCV versions and how can I create a face recognizer object correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [official document](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_api.html#createfisherfacerecognizer),

```
Ptr<FaceRecognizer> createFisherFaceRecognizer(int num_components=0, double threshold=DBL_MAX)
```

is used openCV2. Since you use openCV 4, you have to follow the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d2/de9/classcv_1_1face_1_1FisherFaceRecognizer.html#a0072e4c3f410250baf4b083296a41dfc) that works with openCV 4.

Try this:

```
static Ptr<FisherFaceRecognizer> cv::face::FisherFaceRecognizer::create (int    num_components = 0, double  threshold = DBL_MAX )
```

On the top of [this page](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d2/de9/classcv_1_1face_1_1FisherFaceRecognizer.html#a0072e4c3f410250baf4b083296a41dfc), you can adjust the version of openCV library which you have.

Comment: This helped me out, thanks! Wonder why my Google search didn't throw that up...